# How do you read a single character from console in R (without RETURN)?

Tags: r

Just started using R. Like with any language, I want to be able to step though a program interactively and quickly.

I usually write something like (pseudo code)

```
get_char(char)
if (char == 'q') {return}
if (char == 'a') {list.append(blah)}
if (char is anything else) {just move along}
```

q is for quit and a is for append and they are both right under my left hand on the keyboard so this is as fast as possible.

I see in R I can use

```
char=readline("Type a character and hit Enter")
```

but of course I have to hit enter. Is there a way of just getting a character in R?

Comment: I understand that some things are better performed by humans, but I wonder if you could not set up rules to  deal with your problem rather than manually going through elements.

Comment: This is just standard debugging technique. I would rather just use one hand on my laptop. Obviously not a deal breaker for the language if it can't be done. Just a mild annoyance. So far, I really like R much better than I expected.

Comment: My thought is, if there is a rule that you make a decision on, that rule could be programmed - automating what sounds to be a standard debugging technique.

Comment: I am still at the "looking" stage, not knowing what I want to do exactly. Just want to see each line and save the ones that look like trouble.

Comment: How about putting in `browser()`?

Comment: Or just execute one line at a time, using the keyboard shortcut for your editor.

Comment: I think this is likely to be quite difficult -- in the standard interactive loop, R really doesn't deal with keyboard events at this level of granularity -- the closest it comes is the (special-purpose) `?locator` ... e.g. (from searching "keypress" on http://rseek.org ): http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e2/help/07/07/21839.html , http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/01a/0375.html , http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e4/help/08/01/1101.html

Answer (score 6):

Not a direct answer to your question, but you could use `debug` to get the behaviour you want. If you have a function you want to test, calling `debug(myfunction)` sets up R's debugger, so that when you next call `myfunction()` it is executed one line at a time. If you hit enter inside the debugger, it steps through to the next line of the function. If you want to examine any of the data in scope for the function, or run any other arbitrary R code, you can do that too, as the debugger provides access to all the regular R functions.

Not quite what you want to do with prompting for a single character from the user, but for debugging I think this is much more powerful.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But I still would like to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is shown in the `sudoku::playSudoku` function. On windows, the `getGraphicsEvent` function provides a callback for keyboard input; on other devices, you may use a Tk widget.

There needs to be a graphic device open, however.

Here is an example for windows:

```
dev.new()
getGraphicsEvent(
    "", 
    onKeyb=function(x) 
      if(tolower(x)=="q") 
        return(1) 
      else 
        cat("you pressed a key.\n")
)
```