# *R* Non-blocking console read in R

Tags: r, console, command-line-interface, nonblocking

I am writing a tool in *R* having a crude CLI (Command Line Interface), which does non-blocking reads from a socket (that is working).  I want to concurrently check for new commands, by reading a single character (if it exists) from the console in a non-blocking manner.  A simplified example

```
repeat{
    newCmdChar <- nonblockingReadConsole()
    if (newCmdChar == NULL) doStuffReadingNonblockingSocket()
    else switch(newCmdChar, 
        a = doThis(),
        b = doThat(),
        x = break)
}
```

Various experiments failed with file("stdin") in a nonblocking manner, and permutations on scan(), readLines() etc.  One approach is described here [How do you read a single character from console in R (without RETURN)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980512/how-do-you-read-a-single-character-from-console-in-r-without-return) but it requires working through an open graphics device and I was hoping to avoid that.

Questions

1. is there any way to do nonblockingReadConsole() to get a single
   character? If so, how?
2. better to explore some *R* GUI package?  (I'm
   a newbie, ignorant to those)?  If so, suggestions?

Thanks :)

/george

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that the answer is you probably can't get input from the R GUI command line in a non-blocking way.  It goes against the single-threaded nature of R.

If you need this sort of behaviour, then write the human-interaction part in a different language and call R for the calculations.  Or use one of the GUI toolkits, as described in the question you linked to.

Comment: Your statement certainly matches my experiments to date :)  Thanks for the advise which I anticipate taking.

Answer (score 0):

Update:  I've implemented the "open grDevice with keyboard callback" approach in the link cited above, and it is working out more conveniently than expected.  Cheers, /geg